# Detecting relations with while loop from multiple mysql table using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am try to map the relations between different telephone subscribers (call Pickup group membership, Direct call buttons and other extra features).

The basic subscriber data is stored in a table and the programmed feature data is stored in multiple different tables. I want to run the loop until it is not find any new relations.

The gathered data field value type is INT in all table.

I try to figure out in the past week what is the problem but i am still not figured out why it is not working correctly.

Here is my code:

```
$migrate = $numbers;
        //Store relations in a different array
    do{
            $sel="USE " . $_SESSION['dest'];
            $res= mysqli_query($link,$sel);
                if (!$res) {
                printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($link));
                exit();
                }
                unset($newnumbers);
                $newnumbers = [];
            foreach ($numbers as $src){
            $keres="SELECT * FROM extensions WHERE stno LIKE " . $src;
            $fut=mysqli_query($link,$keres);
            if (!$fut) {
                printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($link));
                exit();
            }
            while ($sor = mysqli_fetch_array($fut)){

                $query="SELECT * FROM dss WHERE srcno LIKE '" . $sor['stno'] . "'";
                $run=mysqli_query($link,$query);
                if (!$run) {
                 printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($link));
                 exit();
                    }
                    while ($name=mysqli_fetch_array($run)){

                        if($name['destno'] != ""){  
                        if(!in_array($name['destno'],$migrate)){
                            $results[]=$name['destno'];     
                            }}}

                if($sor['pickup']!= ""){
                    $query="SELECT * FROM pickup WHERE grno LIKE '" . $sor['pickup'] . "'";
                    $run=mysqli_query($link,$query);
                    if (!$run) {
                        printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($link));
                        exit();
                    }
                        while ($name=mysqli_fetch_array($run)){
                            if($name['stno']!=""){  
                                if(!in_array($name['stno'],$results)){
                                $results[]=$name['stno'];
                                }}}}

                if($sor['chese']!=""){
                    $query="SELECT * FROM chese WHERE grno LIKE '" .  $sor['chese'] . "'";
                    $run=mysqli_query($link,$query);
                    if (!$run) {
                    printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($link));
                    exit();
                    } 
                    while ($cd=mysqli_fetch_array($run)){
                        if($cd['exec1']!="0"){  
                        if(!in_array($cd['exec1'],$results)){
                        $results[]=$cd['exec1'];
                        }}
                        if($cd['exec2']!="0"){
                        if(!in_array($cd['exec2'],$results)){
                        $results[]=$cd['exec2'];
                        }}
                        if($cd['exec3']!="0"){
                        if(!in_array($cd['exec3'],$results)){
                        $results[]=$cd['exec3'];
                        }}
                        if($cd['exec4']!="0"){
                        if(!in_array($cd['exec4'],$results)){
                        $results[]=$cd['exec4'];
                        }}
                        if($cd['secr1']!="0"){
                        if(!in_array($cd['secr1'],$results)){
                        $results[]=$cd['secr1'];
                        }}
                        if($cd['secr2']!="0"){
                        if(!in_array($cd['secr2'],$results)){
                        $results[]=$cd['secr2'];
                        }}
                        if($cd['rep']!="0"){
                        if(!in_array($cd['rep'],$results)){
                        $results[]=$cd['rep'];
                        }}
                        if($cd['rep1']!="0"){
                        if(!in_array($cd['rep1'],$results)){
                        $results[]=$cd['rep1'];
                        }}
                        if($cd['rep2']!="0"){
                        if(!in_array($cd['rep2'],$results)){
                        $results[]=$cd['rep2'];
                        }}
                    }}}} 
                    foreach ($results as $res){
                        if(!in_array($res,$migrate)){
                        $migrate[]=$res;
                        $newnumbers[]=$res;
                        }}
                        unset($numbers);
                        unset($results);
                        $results = [];
                        $numbers = [];
                        $numbers = $newnumbers;

                    }while(count($newnumbers) == "0");
```

Thanks for the help of the community

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: Note: Try and get out of the habit of declaring SQL statements in throw-away variables that are used only once. It's a lot easier to follow code where the query is supplied directly to the function, and there's no longer a chance of messing up and sending in `$sql3` instead of the visually similar `$sql8`.

Comment: You urgently need to read up on using loops and `array` structures to reduce the amount of needless duplication in this code. That wild, tangled `if` block is the same code, over and over and over and over and over and over and overand over and over and over and over.

Comment: Thank you for the advice I started to rewrite the code.